# What is splwow64.exe?

Tags: windows-7, process

What does splwow64.exe do? Why does it run, how does it get triggered?

I've noticed a couple of times that certain applications would freeze up & this process was part of the wait chain, after it crashed it was able to continue using the program again. I did see in the file description it says "print driver host for 32bit applications" but I don't quite understand what this really means- what does it do..., is it safe for me just to randomly crash this program or can it be disabled someway?

Comment: Please [google](http://google.com/search?q=splwow64.exe) before posting.  SU has an expectation of people to do a little leg work up front and ask questions when they get stuck.  If you simply google your keyword (i.e. `splwow64.exe`) then you would find about 10 good sources on it.

Comment: @nerdwaller superuser is one of the few sites that are on my whitelist  at work- google isnt one of them...

Comment: There are more options than just google, here is a good [list of search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines) to help you survive at an awful workplace ;)

Comment: @nerdwaller love my workplace, & wikipedia is also blocked ;-)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 This question is not too broad, #multimodfail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short:**

The process gets executed every time a 32-bit application is accessing one of your installed printers. You could kill the process if you are not actively printing something. It will simply restart the next time you want to print something, e.g., from Word (which is a 32-bit application).

**Explanation:**

WOW64 is the so called "Windows On Windows 64" layer which enables you to execute 32-bit applications on a 64-bit system.

This is why you have the "classic" `System32` (where all the 64-bit binaries are being stored) and the `SysWOW64` folder for the WOW compatibility layer.

However, 32-bit applications cannot use 64-bit binaries (and therefore also printing drivers) and vice versa.

The `splwow64.exe` is a 64-bit application, therefore able to speak with 64-bit printing drivers and "translates" the communication between 32-bit applications and 64-bit drivers.