# System hangs when screensaver runs long

Tags: windows, freeze

I have a dell Laptop running WIN 7 SP1 with 12GB of RAM. When screensaver comes on for over an hour the system hangs. Then I have to do a hard reboot.

Event viewer only denotes that Faulting application name `splwow64`. Sleep is turned off, hibernate is off. And yes, this is a laptop with a docking station.

Answer (score 0):

[splwow64.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/624301/what-is-splwow64-exe) is a Windows 64 "thunk" to translate between a 32-bit application and the 64-bit printer drivers (and spooling).

If you're experiencing issues with it, that implies there are issues with print spooling and/or drivers. Check *System Properties \ Hardware \ Device Manager* for any questionable printer drivers. If your docking station installed software, check for updates.

Leaving a printer on or off *shouldn't* affect stability during sleep, but you might try switching it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

besides event viewer..

there should be a memory dump file which can be a bit like a crash report

If you were to bring up this screen
ctrl..system..advanced system settings.. / startup and recovery..settings

and you see it says the dump is in the file %systemroot%\memory.dmp

You could check the time of it
That said, I don't see that file on my computer.

You can change that drop down menu to "small memory dump"

[image]

[image]

Then it shows `%SystemRoot%\Minidump`

you might have some file there.

Then you'd have to know how to analyze these things or find somewhere where they read memory dumps

Personally, the crashes i've had have usually been BSODs and they normally have all the info I need there.. but maybe a memory dump is useful for you if you're not getting much info 'cos you get no BSOD, just a freeze.

If you find you can't see a memory dump file, then i'm not sure why, but maybe you could look into that.